# Microsoft Access query assistance

Tags: ms-access

I have a database I use to track personnel for my job and often I have to import new rosters from 2 different sources. The two sources list the names differently.
1st table: Alpha
2nd Table: DRMD

The 1st table allows up to 32 characters such as: ASHLEYJOHNSON, DEVAUGHN GARY
The 2nd table only allows for 19 characters, such as: ASHLEYJOHNSON, DEVA

Is there a query I can run that will show me the names in table 1 (ALPHA) that are similar to the names in table 2 (DRMD)? Both tables have the names listed in the field (Name), i.e., [ALPHA].[NAME] and [DRMD].[NAME]

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding a WHERE statement of:

WHERE [DRMD].[NAME] = LEFT([ALPHA].[NAME], 19)

would work. Both tables in the query, no join commands.

Comment: It worked!. Some of the names didn't match, i.e., Cruz Montero, Jose as compared to Cruz, Montero Jose. Thank you!!!